# Password expiration in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps, google-provisioning-api

Is it possible, with Google Provisioning API, to set an expiration date to the password?
Or to check when the password was set?

```
 <apps:login userName="NewUserName" 
  password="51eea05d46317fadd5cad6787a8f562be90b4446" hashFunctionName="SHA-1"
  suspended="false"/>
```

According to the protocol example there are only few fields but maybe some other fields are hidden like in other apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but no there is not.

What you could do, is do a SSO but against Google Apps.

Most of the documentation about SSO asumes that you need to authenticate against LDAP/Ad.
But I have developed a few that authenticate directly against Google.

There are 2 reasons:
1 - clients hate the "non-corporate" login screen 
2 - I can enforce password expiration (part off the SSO is developing the password change)

In theory, you could develop this in App Engine.

Good luck!